# How to clone an element using class name and append it to the body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to learn how to clone an element using classname and append it to the body.
here is what i have done but i am not getting any output. is there anything wrong ?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="check">hello</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 .check {
     top: 100px;
 }
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('.check');
var temp = elem[0].clonenode(true);
document.body.append(temp);
```

JSFiddle Link:

http://jsfiddle.net/hAw53/378/

if not JS, jquery solution is also welcomed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there:

```js
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('check'); // remove the dot from the class name
var temp = elem[0].cloneNode(true); // capitalise "Node"
document.body.appendChild(temp); // change "append" to "appendChild"
```

```html
<div class="check">hello</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 errors. Correct code:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('check'); // check, not .check
var temp = elem[0].cloneNode(true);  // cloneNode, not clonenode
document.body.appendChild(temp); // appendChild, not append
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hAw53/379/

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues with your code.

- [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.getElementsByClassName) takes a class name (`check`), not a selector (`.check`)
- [`cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode) is spelled with a capital N (not `clonenode()`)
- [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FNode.appendChild) is the name of the DOM method for appending a child (not `append()`)

Correct version:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('check');
var temp = elem[0].cloneNode(true);
document.body.appendChild(temp);
```

Comment: `append()` is also a method for appending a child. question is tagged with [tag:jquery] as well...

Comment: @TJ, sure, `append()` is a jQuery method, but not a DOM method. The code in question is DOM, not jQuery.

Comment: Yes, then you should mention it to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$('.check').clone().appendTo('body');
```

You're code had errors. First you used class selector and not the class name. Then you used an undefined property(properties are case sensitive) and you've to use `appendChild` instead of `append` which is a part of jQuery. You're too much confused with native javascript and jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

in Jquery it's very simple, you just need to define inside what the new element apears.

```
var elem = $('.check');
elem.clone().prependTo( "body");
```